# Error getting .htaccess to direct googlebot using _escaped_fragment_

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, seo

I am trying to get my pages indexed on google using a prerendering service for my backbone app.

I know the setup works fine when I specifically add googlebot to the useragent list but Ive been advised against this in favor of using the _escaped_fragment_ method. Only problem is the _escaped_fragment_ parameter isn't getting passed correctly. Can some help please?

thanks!!!

```
    # html5 pushstate (history) support:

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# If requested resource exists as a file or directory
# (REQUEST_FILENAME is only relative in virtualhost context, so not usable)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
# Go to it as is
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If non existent
  # If path ends with / and is not just a single /, redirect to without the trailing /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R,QSA,L]      

  # Handle Prerender.io
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "xxxxxxxx"

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR] 
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

# Proxy the request
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://www.example.com/$2 [P,L]

  # If non existent

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L,QSA]


</ifModule>
```

All the apache modules are loaded and working.

Comment: Have you added the `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` code in the html header or in your link ?

Comment: The pages you try to show with a prerendering service are not real files ? (because forward you exclude real files with -f)

Answer (score 0):

So the .htaccess is actually correct... here Google's official answer.

Quote from http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/bZgWCJTnl08%5B1-25%5D by John Mueller (google employee)

```
Looking at your blog's homepage, one thing to keep in mind is that the Fetch
as Googlebot feature does not parse the content that it fetches. So when you
submit toddmoyer.net/blog/ , it fetches that URL. After fetching the URL, it
doesn't parse it to check for the "fragment" meta tag, it just returns it to
you. However, if you fetch toddmoyer.net/blog/#! , then it should rewrite the
URL and fetch the URL toddmoyer.net/blog/?_escaped_fragment_= .

When we crawl and index your pages, we'll notice the meta-tag and act
accordingly. It's just the Fetch as Googlebot feature that doesn't check for
meta-tags, and instead just returns the raw content.
```